# storing multiple values in a single variable?

Tags: php

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="A" />
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="B" />
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="C" />
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="D" />
</form>

<?php
  $letters = $_POST['foo'];
?>
```

each time form submit $letters will be filled with respective values. so $letters can be "A" or "B" or "C" etc.

is it possible store all submitted values at a time? say when I echo $letters it should give "ABCD" or "BCDBA" or whatever order form is submitted.

I think this can be done through $_SESSION but no Idea how...any ideas?

Comment: 1. I think you mean `$_SESSION`. 2. A user can only click on one button at a time. Are you displaying the form multiple times? What exactly do you want to do? What is the form for?

Answer (score 2):

Hy
Try make the attribute name in each submit button: name="foo[]"
Then, in php, $_POST['foo'] contains an array with the value of each "foo[]"

```
echo implode('', $_POST['foo']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the session, so first: `$_SESSION['letters']=array();` and then each post you can do `$_SESSION['letters'][] = $_POST['foo'];` and then you will have an ordered array.

This is how the top of your page will look:

`session_start(); //important that this is first thing in the document
if ( !$_SESSION['letters'] ) {
    $_SESSION['letters'] = array(); //create the session variable if it doesn't exist
}
if ( $_POST['foo'] ) { //if foo has been posted back
    $_SESSION['letters'][] = $_POST['foo'];  // the [] after the session variable means add to the array
}`

You can use `print_r $_SESSION['letters'];` to output the array as a string, or you can use any of the many php array functions to manipulate the data.

Comment: I mean how do I retrieve this value?

Comment: @homlyn: sorry, I didn't understand what you meant, $_SESSION['letters'] is the variable, you could make a new variable $letters = $_SESSION['letters'] when you are finished saving the information so you can work with it more easily

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$email_to = "";
$get= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `newsletter`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
    $email_to = $email_to.",".$row['mail'];
}

echo $email_to;
```